# Realizacion de una vista de un componente react

Tags: reactjs

tengo que realizar una vista con preguntas que me llegan desde el backend, el problema es que son 3 tipos de preguntas, 1 es input y las otras 2 son de tipo checkbox, 1 checkbox te permite seleccionar 1 sola respuesta y el otro checkbox varias respuestas. La peticion GET al backend me trae todas las preguntas en este JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "Proporcione una descripción general y una presentación de su organización",
    "indicator_code": "C0.1",
    "parameter_id": 1,
    "name": "5000 caracteres",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "Indique la fecha de comienzo y de finalización del año para el que presenta los datos",
    "indicator_code": "C0.2",
    "parameter_id": 2,
    "name": "Fecha de comienzo",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "Indique la fecha de comienzo y de finalización del año para el que presenta los datos",
    "indicator_code": "C0.2",
    "parameter_id": 3,
    "name": "Fecha de finalización",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "Indique la fecha de comienzo y de finalización del año para el que presenta los datos",
    "indicator_code": "C0.2",
    "parameter_id": 4,
    "name": "Indique si proporcionará datos de emisiones para años de reporte anteriores",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "Indique la fecha de comienzo y de finalización del año para el que presenta los datos",
    "indicator_code": "C0.2",
    "parameter_id": 5,
    "name": "Seleccione el número de años de reporte anteriores para los que proporcionará datos de emisiones",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "Seleccione los países/las áreas en las que opera",
    "indicator_code": "C0.3",
    "parameter_id": 6,
    "name": "",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "Seleccione la moneda utilizada para toda la información financiera divulgada en su respuesta",
    "indicator_code": "C0.4",
    "parameter_id": 7,
    "name": "",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "Indique la opción que mejor describa alcance de la divulgación de información dentro del cual se informan los impactos relacionados con el clima en su actividad comercial. Observe que esta opción debe estar alineada con el enfoque de consolidación de su inventario de GEI seleccionado",
    "indicator_code": "C0.5",
    "parameter_id": 8,
    "name": "Seleccione una de las siguientes opciones",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "¿Qué actividades realiza su organización, y a qué sectores de la industria su organización proporciona servicios de préstamo, inversión o seguros?",
    "indicator_code": "C-FS0.7",
    "parameter_id": 9,
    "name": "Actividad",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "¿Qué actividades realiza su organización, y a qué sectores de la industria su organización proporciona servicios de préstamo, inversión o seguros?",
    "indicator_code": "C-FS0.7",
    "parameter_id": 10,
    "name": "¿Su organización realiza esta actividad?",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "¿Qué actividades realiza su organización, y a qué sectores de la industria su organización proporciona servicios de préstamo, inversión o seguros?",
    "indicator_code": "C-FS0.7",
    "parameter_id": 11,
    "name": "Tipos de seguros proporcionados",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "¿Qué actividades realiza su organización, y a qué sectores de la industria su organización proporciona servicios de préstamo, inversión o seguros?",
    "indicator_code": "C-FS0.7",
    "parameter_id": 12,
    "name": "Sectores de la industria a los que su organización proporciona servicios de préstamo, inversión o seguro",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "¿Su organización tiene un código ISIN u otro identificador único (por ejemplo, Ticker, CUSIP, etc.)?",
    "indicator_code": "C0.8",
    "parameter_id": 13,
    "name": "Indique si puede proporcionar un identificador único para su organización",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "¿Su organización tiene un código ISIN u otro identificador único (por ejemplo, Ticker, CUSIP, etc.)?",
    "indicator_code": "C0.8",
    "parameter_id": 14,
    "name": "Proporcione su identificador único",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "¿Existe la supervisión de asuntos relacionados con el clima por parte de la junta directiva en su organización?",
    "indicator_code": "C1.1",
    "parameter_id": 15,
    "name": "Seleccione una de las siguientes opciones",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "Identifique el(los) cargo (s) (sin incluir nombres) de la(s) persona(s) en la Junta Directiva que es(son) responsable(s) de los asuntos relacionados con el clima",
    "indicator_code": "C1.1a",
    "parameter_id": 16,
    "name": "cargo de la(s) persona(s)",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "Identifique el(los) cargo (s) (sin incluir nombres) de la(s) persona(s) en la Junta Directiva que es(son) responsable(s) de los asuntos relacionados con el clima",
    "indicator_code": "C1.1a",
    "parameter_id": 17,
    "name": "Por favor, explique",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "standar": "CDP",
    "turn": "Servicios Financieros",
    "indicator": "Proporcione más detalles sobre la supervisión de los asuntos relacionados con el clima por parte de la Junta Directiva",
    "indicator_code": "C1.1b",
    "parameter_id": 18,
    "name": "Frecuencia con la que los asuntos relacionados con el clima se incluyen en la agenda como un elemento planificado",
    "type_data": null,
    "description": null,
    "level": 1
  }
]
```

Para saber si es input o checkbox tengo que realizar 2 POST a la misma direccion pero con distinto body, el primer POST es con el body:

```
{
    "standard_code": "CDP"
}
```

este me devuelve el JSON:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "indicators": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Proporcione una descripción general y una presentación de su organización",
    "code": "C0.1",
    "description": "",
    "update_frequency": "",
    "measurement_units": "",
    "goal_target": "",
    "acceptable_value_range": "",
    "init": true,
    "standard": 1,
    "calculation_method": null
  },
  "name": "5000 caracteres",
  "description": null,
  "data_type": null,
  "capture_periodicity": null,
  "data_source": null,
  "type": "PAR",
  "required_validations": null,
  "relationship_with_indicators": null,
  "creation_date": null,
  "last_modification_date": null,
  "nivel": 1,
  "string_id": "CDP_C0.1_1",
  "dependency": [
    {
      "code": "CDP_C0.2_1"
    }
  ],
  "init": true
}
```

este es de tipo input porque la propiedad dependency contiene solo code(esa es la condicion para que sea input)
El segundo POST es con el body:

```
{
    "dependency_id": "CDP_C1.1a_1"
}
```

este me devuelve el JSON:

```
{
  "id": 16,
  "indicators": {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Identifique el(los) cargo (s) (sin incluir nombres) de la(s) persona(s) en la Junta Directiva que es(son) responsable(s) de los asuntos relacionados con el clima",
    "code": "C1.1a",
    "description": "",
    "update_frequency": "",
    "measurement_units": "",
    "goal_target": "",
    "acceptable_value_range": "",
    "init": false,
    "standard": 1,
    "calculation_method": null
  },
  "name": "cargo de la(s) persona(s)",
  "description": null,
  "data_type": null,
  "capture_periodicity": null,
  "data_source": null,
  "type": "PAR",
  "required_validations": null,
  "relationship_with_indicators": null,
  "creation_date": null,
  "last_modification_date": null,
  "nivel": 1,
  "string_id": "CDP_C1.1a_1",
  "dependency": [
    {
      "option": "Presidente de la Junta Directiva",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    },
    {
      "option": "Director de la Junta Directiva",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    },
    {
      "option": "Director Ejecutivo (CEO)",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    },
    {
      "option": "Director de Finanzas (CFO)",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    },
    {
      "option": "Director de Operaciones (COO)",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    },
    {
      "option": "Director de Adquisición (CPO)",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    },
    {
      "option": "Director de Riesgos (CRO)",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    },
    {
      "option": "Director de Sustentabilidad (CSO)",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    },
    {
      "option": "Director de Inversión (CIO) [solamente para los servicios financieros]",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    },
    {
      "option": "Director de Crédito (CCO) [solamente para los servicios financieros]",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    },
    {
      "option": "Director de Emisión de Seguros (CUO) [solamente para los servicios financieros]",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    },
    {
      "option": "Otro directivo de primera línea",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    },
    {
      "option": "Presidente",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    },
    {
      "option": "Comité de nivel de Junta Directiva",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    },
    {
      "option": "Otro. Especifique.",
      "code": "CDP_C1.1a_2"
    }
  ],
  "init": true
}
```

Aca dependency contiene option y code(esa es la condicion para que sea checkbox)
Les paso mi codigo que no funciona para ver si me pueden orientar por donde esta el error, este codigo me trae y muestra todas las preguntas del backend pero siempre mostrandonme inputs por pantalla, no puedo hacer que detecte y renderice las preguntas que son checkbox. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";
    import {
      TextField,
      Button,
      Card,
      CardContent,
      Typography,
      FormGroup,
      FormControlLabel,
      Checkbox,
    } from "@mui/material";
    import styles from "./styles.module.css"; // Ajusta el nombre del archivo a styles.module.css
    
    export default function Esg() {
      const [preguntas, setPreguntas] = useState([]);
      const [respuesta, setRespuesta] = useState("");
      const [mostrarSiguiente, setMostrarSiguiente] = useState(false);
      const [preguntaIndex, setPreguntaIndex] = useState(0);
      const [preguntasTerminadas, setPreguntasTerminadas] = useState(false);
    
      const url_tsapi = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL_TSAPI;
      const accessToken = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_TOKEN;
    
      useEffect(() => {
        obtenerPreguntasDesdeBackend("CDP"); // Llamada inicial al backend
      }, []);
      const esCheckBox = () => {
        const preguntaActual = preguntas[preguntaIndex];
        console.log(preguntaActual.indicator.type);
        if (preguntaActual) {
          const type = preguntaActual.indicator.type;
      
          return type === "checkbox";
        }
      
        return false;
      };
    
      const obtenerPreguntasDesdeBackend = async (standardCode, option) => {
        try {
          // Construir la URL con los parámetros necesarios
          const url =
            `${url_tsapi}generate_report/?standard_code=${standardCode}` +
            (option ? `&option=${option}` : "");
    
          const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Authorization: `Token ${accessToken}`,
            },
          });
    
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(
              `Error al obtener preguntas desde el backend: ${response.statusText}`
            );
          }
    
          const data = await response.json();
          console.log("Respuesta del backend:", data);
          if (data.length > 0) {
            setPreguntas(data);
            setPreguntaIndex(0);
            setMostrarSiguiente(true);
            setPreguntasTerminadas(false);
          } else {
            console.log("No hay más preguntas");
            setPreguntasTerminadas(true); // Actualiza el estado cuando no hay más preguntas
            setMostrarSiguiente(false);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error al obtener preguntas desde el backend:", error);
        }
      };
    
      const realizarPost = async (body) => {
        try {
          console.log("Realizando POST con body:", body);
    
          // Hacer una llamada al backend con el body proporcionado
          const response = await fetch(`${url_tsapi}generate_report/`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Authorization: `Token ${accessToken}`,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
          });
    
          const responseData = await response.json();
          console.log("Respuesta del POST:", responseData);
    
          // Puedes devolver 'responseData' si es necesario para manejar la respuesta en otro lugar
          return responseData;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error en realizarPost:", error);
          // Puedes lanzar el error para manejarlo en la función llamante
          throw error;
        }
      };
      const manejarRespuesta = async () => {
        try {
          setMostrarSiguiente(false);
    
          const preguntaActual = preguntas[preguntaIndex];
    
          if (!preguntaActual) {
            console.log("No hay más preguntas");
            setPreguntasTerminadas(true);
            setMostrarSiguiente(true);
            return;
          }
          // Log de depuración para verificar la estructura de preguntaActual
          if (preguntaActual && preguntaActual.indicator) {
            // Accede a las propiedades de 'indicator' aquí
            console.log(preguntaActual.indicator);
          } else {
            console.error(
              "La propiedad 'indicator' no está definida como un objeto en la pregunta actual."
            );
          }
    
          console.log("Estructura de preguntaActual:", preguntaActual);
    
          // Verificar si 'indicator' está definido y es un objeto
          if (
            "indicator" in preguntaActual &&
            typeof preguntaActual.indicator === "object" &&
            preguntaActual.indicator !== null
          ) {
            const { indicator } = preguntaActual;
            const { standar } = indicator;
    
            // Verificar si 'standar' está definido y tiene un valor
            if (standar) {
              const { indicator_code, dependency } = preguntaActual;
    
              // Comprobar el tipo de pregunta (checkbox o input)
              if (dependency && dependency.length > 0) {
                // Es una pregunta de tipo checkbox
                const respuestaCheckbox = await realizarPost({
                  dependency_id: dependency[0].code,
                  // Otros campos necesarios para el POST
                });
    
                console.log("Respuesta del POST (checkbox):", respuestaCheckbox);
              } else {
                // Es una pregunta de tipo input
                const respuestaInput = await realizarPost({
                  standard_code: standar,
                  indicator_code: indicator_code,
                  // Otros campos necesarios para el POST
                });
    
                console.log("Respuesta del POST (input):", respuestaInput);
              }
            } else {
              console.error(
                "La propiedad 'indicator.standar' no tiene un valor definido en la pregunta actual."
              );
            }
          } else {
            console.error(
              "La propiedad 'indicator' no está definida como un objeto en la pregunta actual."
            );
    
            // Puedes manejar el caso donde no hay 'indicator'
            // Agregar aquí cualquier lógica adicional que necesites
          }
          // Reiniciamos la respuesta después de manejarla
          setRespuesta("");
    
          if (preguntas.length > preguntaIndex + 1) {
            setPreguntaIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1);
            setMostrarSiguiente(true);
          } else {
            console.log("No hay más preguntas");
            setPreguntasTerminadas(true);
            setMostrarSiguiente(true);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error al manejar la respuesta:", error);
          // Puedes agregar aquí cualquier lógica adicional para manejar el error
        }
      };
    
      const preguntaContainerRef = useRef(null);
    
      return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <Card sx={{ width: "75%" }}>
            <CardContent>
              <CSSTransition
                key={preguntaIndex}
                in={mostrarSiguiente}
                timeout={300}
                classNames="fade"
                unmountOnExit
              >
                <div
                  ref={preguntaContainerRef}
                  className={styles.questionContainer}
                >
                  {preguntasTerminadas ? (
                    <Typography variant="h6">
                      ¡Se han completado todas las preguntas!
                    </Typography>
                  ) : (
                    <>
                      <Typography variant="h6">
                        {preguntas[preguntaIndex]?.indicator}
                      </Typography>
                      <div className={styles.answerContainer}>
                        {/* Renderizar el input o checkbox basado en el tipo de pregunta */}
                        {esCheckBox()?.type !== "input" ? (
                          <TextField
                            placeholder="Escriba aquí su respuesta"
                            value={respuesta}
                            onChange={(e) => setRespuesta(e.target.value)}
                            variant="outlined"
                            fullWidth
                            InputProps={{
                              style: {
                                width: "95%",
                                fontSize: "18px",
                                color: "white",
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",
                              },
                            }}
                          />
                        ) : (
                          <FormGroup>
                            {preguntas[preguntaIndex]?.dependency?.map(
                              (opcion, idx) => (
                                <FormControlLabel
                                  key={idx}
                                  control={
                                    <Checkbox
                                      value={opcion.code}
                                      onChange={(e) =>
                                        setRespuesta((prev) => {
                                          const newArr = e.target.checked
                                            ? [...prev, opcion]
                                            : prev.filter(
                                                (item) => item.code !== opcion.code
                                              );
                                          console.log("Nueva respuesta:", newArr);
                                          return newArr;
                                        })
                                      }
                                      checked={respuesta.some(
                                        (item) => item.code === opcion.code
                                      )}
                                    />
                                  }
                                  label={opcion.option}
                                />
                              )
                            )}
                          </FormGroup>
                        )}
    
                        <Button
                          variant="contained"
                          color="success"
                          onClick={manejarRespuesta}
                          style={{ width: "fit-content" }}
                        >
                          Siguiente
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    </>
                  )}
                </div>
              </CSSTransition>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    }
```